# Filtrar texto no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Como filtrar o `1` de `"status":1`, do texto abaixo usando *Delphi*:

```
{"status":1,"data":"47281274","msg":"SUCESSO"}
```

Tentei algumas rotinas de `StrReplace`, porém sem sucesso!

Answer (score 4):

O que você pode utilizar são as classes responsáveis por manipular JSON no Delphi, este texto que você passou nada mais é que um JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).

Documentação sobre JSON no site da Embarcadero: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/JSON

Exemplo manipulando JSON:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815625/parsing-valid-json-with-tjsonobject-using-embarcadero-code-example-fails-with-ex

Exemplo que criei utilizando o texto que você postou, pegando o Status somente e retornando um evento ShowMessage com o valor contido em Status.

```
procedure showMessageWithStatus;
var 
    vJSONString : string;
    vJSONPair : TJSONPair;
    vJSONScenario: TJSONObject;
    vParseResult : Integer;
    vJSONScenarioEntry: TJSONValue;
    vJSONScenarioValue: string;
begin
    vJSONString := '{"status":1,"data":"47281274","msg":"SUCESSO"}';
    try
        vJSONScenario := TJSONObject.Create;
        vParseResult := vJSONScenario.Parse(BytesOf(vJSONString),0);
        if  vParseResult >= 0 then
        begin
            vJSONPair := vJSONScenario.Get('status');
            vJSONScenarioEntry := vJSONPair.JsonValue;
            vJSONScenarioValue := vJSONScenarioEntry.Value;
            ShowMessage(vJSONScenarioValue);  
        end;
    finally
        vJSONScenario.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Qualquer dúvida estamos a disposição.